# SQL query for stacked bar chart

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

In my project I'm trying to write a query to fetch data for a stacked bar graph. Instead of explaining the schema of my DB (which would be lengthy), I found a similar analogy which I can port to my DB later.

[On this page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all), run the query

```
SELECT * FROM [Products]
```

In the table, if I want to select data for stacked bar graph as below, how do I form the query?

- one bar for each CategoryID
- within each CategoryID, I want the number of products that use bags, bottles or jars (Substring in Unit column)

Sorry, I'm not able to demonstrate substantial research effort in this, as I'm not even able to visualize what the SELECT clause would look like. I tried to check if we can use AS in WHERE clause and then do a COUNT on it. But that does not seem to be correct syntax.

I'm going to be running the actual query on MS SQL Server through PowerBI

Comment: you will have these three - "bags, bottles or jars " in unit column or more?

Comment: Each value in Unit column will have a string or NULL. If it is a string, it MAY have bag, bottle or jar somewhere in the string or it may not. But I know the values to look for (they are: bag, bottle or jar), nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step will be to create a flag for bags, bottles, and jars. This can be done in either SQL or Power BI.

For SQL, use a query like this:

```
SELECT *
    ,   CASE
            WHEN Products.Unit LIKE '%bag%' THEN 'Bag'
            WHEN Products.Unit LIKE '%bottle%' THEN 'Bottle'
            WHEN Products.Unit LIKE '%jar%' THEN 'Jar'
            ELSE 'Other'
        END AS 'UnitFlag'
FROM dbo.Products
```

For Power BI, use DAX to create a new column with this formula:

```
UnitFlag = IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("bag", Products[Unit]), -1) > 1, "Bag",
    IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Bottle", Products[Unit]), -1) > 1, "Bottle",
        IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Jar", Products[Unit]), -1) > 1, "Jar",
            "Other"
        )
    )
)
```

Then just configure your stacked chart as shown below.

[image: Graph]

From here, you can change a couple of settings to make the graph look a little nicer; for instance, changing the X-Axis to be treated as Categorical instead of Continuous and hiding the "Other" category if you don't want that visible.

Comment: This is certainly helpful. Thanks a lot. Can you also post your formula for UnitFlags measure that you have used in PowerBI?

Comment: I didn't create any measures in Power BI; I only created a new column using the DAX formula in my answer.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry, my bad.

Comment: No worries. I know that Power BI and DAX can be confusing when you're just starting out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to learn about aggregation:

```
select categoryID, 
       reverse(left(reverse(unit), charindex(' ',reverse(unit))-1)) as Unit_type, -- gets the last word of `UNIT`
       count(*) as Total_Products
from Products
group by categoryID, 
         reverse(left(reverse(unit), charindex(' ',reverse(unit))-1))
```

What this will do is count all of the rows and group by Unit type and categoryID. Try it, see what happens.

I would suggest that you learn about aggregation sooner rather than later, it's incredibly powerful.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Yes Aggregation is something new for me (even SQL is new for me). Sorry, but your soln is not exactly what I need. Your solution lists categoryID from each row and it's corresponding productID, i think. Total_Products column contains only 1s, since it is not aggregating. Also, one important point of substring on Unit is missed out.